# How to store any class object in an hash map

Tags: hashmap, crystal-lang

I have a hash map which acts as store of objects - where key is class name & value is object

```
store = {} of String => Type 

store["Animal"]= Animal.new
store["Book"]= Book.new
store["Car"]= Car.new
```

Here class is unknown to me, which means i can't use union type. Please tell me how to solve this problem ?

I am trying to create a wrapper around hash map for storage of objects, which will save object & return object by key.

Update 1

Classes will be passed as a parameter - like this

```
add_in_store(Animal)
add_in_store(Person)
```

Update 2

Crystal play link of what i am trying to do - https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/8lwx

Solution of problem doesn't have to be in same way as what i m doing. It can be with any other approach like using proc or macro etc.

Comment: Do you know all the classes you will store? If so, there is a way.

Comment: no, i don't know what classes will be used, but consider classes being passed as parameter. Think it like a library.

Comment: You want typing on the return value in the IDE for a get operation? I've written caching libraries like this, but you are at the limits wanting it to be dynamic at runtime and statically typed at design time... Maybe add the API you want it to have to the question.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed this is a crystal-lang question! I was trying to solve it in TypeScript. Sorry, I defs don't know how to do it in Crystal. The closest thing I've found in TS is io-ts. You may need higher-kinded types to do this level of magic. It is like a generic, but it needs to make a statement about a runtime property. Maybe a custom base class, or reflection. Sorry, can't help further on this one. Hope you get a solution (update if you do) - it's an interesting problem!

Comment: There's no way to do what you want

Comment: @asterite ok i see, are you planing to include this in future ?

Comment: @asterite i have made this question generic, so that other people can also take advantage of it. But actually i am trying to build a dependency injection store, so taking dependency from user and injecting it in run time. I am able to do this for primitive data type but issue is when user specify their own classes , structs etc.

Let me know if its possible by any way.

Comment: No plans to include this in the future, at least from my side. Why do you need such functionality?

Comment: I am working on a http server framework, where i am trying to provide dependency injection functionality.

Comment: @asterite, for singleton - i need to store multiple objects & provide these objects at run time.

Comment: If it's dependency injection you usually relate a type to many implementations, so you don't need Object. There are some dependency injection libraries in Crystal, maybe research how they are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash` is a generic type, to wrap it in a way where you cannot or don't want to restrict the possible types of the generic arguments, you should make your wrapper itself generic.

```
class Store(V)
  @store = {} of String => V 

  def add(name, value : V)
    @store[name] = value 
  end 
end
```

Then the consumer of your wrapper has to give the possible types.

Comment: but this would store class of one type right ? i can not store instance of class Animal & Person inside one store which mean i will have to create multiple instance of class`Store` . Now problem is how to store all `Store` instance ?

Comment: here is crystal play link of your suggestion - https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/8lwt

Comment: that works if you know the type, but as i said i am working on library - so it can be any user defined class.

Comment: Well make sure the user interface of your library is generic so the user can specify what the type is.